# Is it possible to filter events by daterange which occur on a single day, i.e. have the same start date and end date?

Tags: search-facet, sxa-search

Using the daterange filter to filter search results in Sitecore, the filter works for events which span more than 1 day but if you try to filter for events that start and end on the same day, we get no results, even though the start and end date fields are set to the same day in the datasource. Is there a way to filter events to show single day events only?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your scope query and the corresponding search query as it appears in the log file?

Comment: Scope query:
+location:{9AD4F616-DFC7-46B4-8151-D0768DD5F8F6};+template:{5f82fdd3-25ac-45c6-aa2f-22128cc28e64};

Where location is pointing to /sitecore/content/Portal Sites/Site/Data/Events

and template is pointing to /sitecore/templates/Feature/Events/Data Templates/Calendar Event